the trait bound `I: scale_info::TypeInfo` is not satisfied
I am writing Pallet which has generic parameter T and static parameter I, but as soon as I wish to create storage for Struct with generic parameter T I receive tons of errors. What am I doing wrong?
Here is struct snippet:
#[derive(Encode, Decode, MaxEncodedLen, TypeInfo, Clone, PartialEq, Default, Debug)]
    #[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
    pub struct Proposal<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> {
        proposal_id: u64,
        number_of_different_owners: u64,
        number_of_votes: Votes,
        end_time: BlockNumberFor<T>,
    }

and here is storage:
#[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn proposals)]
    pub type Proposals<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> = StorageMap<
    _,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    u64, 
    Proposal<T, I>,  // Proposal structure
    >;

The error I receive:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `I: scale_info::TypeInfo` is not satisfied
     --> /Users/dudo50/Documents/GitHub/polkadot-sdk/templates/parachain/pallets/pallet/src/lib.rs:194:12
      |
  194 |       #[pallet::storage]
      |  _______________^
  195 | |     #[pallet::getter(fn proposals)]
  196 | |     pub type Proposals<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> = StorageMap<
      | |________________________________^ the trait `scale_info::TypeInfo` is not implemented for `I`, which is required by `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageProposals<T, I>, frame_support::Blake2_128Concat, u64, Proposal<T, I>>: StorageEntryMetadataBuilder`
      |
  note: required for `Proposal<T, I>` to implement `scale_info::TypeInfo`
     --> /Users/dudo50/Documents/GitHub/polkadot-sdk/templates/parachain/pallets/pallet/src/lib.rs:137:42
      |
  137 |     #[derive(Encode, Decode, MaxEncodedLen, TypeInfo, Clone, PartialEq, Default, Debug)]
      |                                             ^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced in this `derive` macro
  138 |     #[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
  139 |     pub struct Proposal<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> {
      |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      = note: required for `Proposal<T, I>` to implement `StaticTypeInfo`
      = note: required for `StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageProposals<T, I>, Blake2_128Concat, u64, Proposal<T, I>>` to implement `StorageEntryMetadataBuilder`
      = note: the full name for the type has been written to '/Users/dudo50/Documents/GitHub/polkadot-sdk/target/release/wbuild/parachain-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/pallet_parachain_pallet-27936525c5111ac6.long-type-2362683479117901834.txt'
      = note: consider using `--verbose` to print the full type name to the console
      = note: this error originates in the derive macro `TypeInfo` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
  help: consider restricting type parameter `I`
      |
  70  | #[frame_support::pallet] scale_info::TypeInfo

I did try to debug it, but only when I change parameters of the structure to non generic and non static errors disappear.
Many thanks for any advice!

Resolved by adding I to scale_info skip_type_params.
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T, I))]
